# Initialize and access with index an unknowable number of list in dictionnary

Tags: c#, xml, list, dictionary, object

I have this problem that keep me up at night. It's pretty long to explain so thanks in advance for the time you dedicate to this topic.

### The context

I want to make a class in C# to get the entire content of an XML file with nodes names as index and sorted in a tree way using a combinations of Lists and Dictionaries.

The goal is to be able to access a specific data using names and index like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(xmlContent["employee"][0]["e-mail"][1]);
//Would return the second email from the first employee register in the xml file.
```

I'm almost certain that it is possible. I quickly create something similar using one List and two Dictionaries:

```
        List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> test = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> column1 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> column2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

        Dictionary<string, string> C1ligne1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        C1ligne1.Add("value1", "C1ligne1 1");
        C1ligne1.Add("value2", "C1ligne1 2");

        Dictionary<string, string> C1ligne2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        C1ligne2.Add("value1", "C1ligne2 1");
        C1ligne2.Add("value2", "C1ligne2 2");

        Dictionary<string, string> C2ligne1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        C2ligne1.Add("value1", "C2ligne1 1");
        C2ligne1.Add("value2", "C2ligne1 2");

        Dictionary<string, string> C2ligne2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        C2ligne2.Add("value1", "C2ligne2 1");
        C2ligne2.Add("value2", "C2ligne2 2");

        column1.Add("line1", C1ligne1);
        column1.Add("line2", C1ligne2);

        column2.Add("line1", C2ligne1);
        column2.Add("line2", C2ligne2);

        test.Add(column1);
        test.Add(column2);

        Console.WriteLine(test[0]["line1"]["value1"]); //"C1ligne1 1"
        Console.WriteLine(test[0]["line2"]["value2"]); //"C1ligne2 2"
        Console.WriteLine(test[1]["line1"]["value2"]); //"C2ligne1 2"
```

It work really well!

### The problem

I managed to make what I wanted using a method and a function, it work just the way I wanted:

```
    public void getContent(ref Dictionary<string, List<Object>> content)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (!content.ContainsKey(node.Name))
            {
                content.Add(node.Name, new List<Object>());
                content[node.Name].Add(this.nodeContent(node));
            }
            else
            {
                content[node.Name].Add(this.nodeContent(node));
            }
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, List<Object>> nodeContent(XmlNode specificNode)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<Object>> content = new Dictionary<string, List<Object>>();

        foreach (XmlNode nodeInSpecificNode in specificNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (nodeInSpecificNode.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
            {
                content.Add(nodeInSpecificNode.Name, new List<object>  ());
                content[nodeInSpecificNode.Name].Add(this.nodeContent(nodeInSpecificNode));
            }
            else
            {
                content.Add(nodeInSpecificNode.Name, new List<Object>());
                content[nodeInSpecificNode.Name].Add(nodeInSpecificNode.InnerText);
            }
        }

        return content;
    }
```

Unfortunately it force me to use list of Object since I cannot know how much child nodes will be in each nodes. This make me unable to access multiple childs nodes like I showed in the first part because Object are not List.

### The question

Is there a way to actually solve this?
I though of a way to cast the list of object into list of Dictionary based on my needs but I really have no clue of how it would work.

Comment: Using `XmlElement` or `XmlDocument` it will look like this: `xmlContent["employee"].ChildNodes[0]["e-mail"].ChildNodes[1]`. Maybe you're reinventing a bicycle.

Comment: You're right and it work well better your way than mine. To be honest i didn't know it was possible to access nodes content like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid nested generic types you can create some non-generic class wrappers with indexers and move the definition of a dictionary or a list inside:

```
public class DictionaryNode 
{
    public Dictionary<string, ListNode> Dictionary { get; } = new Dictionary<string, ListNode>();

    public ListNode this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return Dictionary[name];
        }
    }
}

public class ListNode 
{
    public List<DictionaryNode> List { get; } = new List<DictionaryNode>();

    public DictionaryNode this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return List[index];
        }
    }

    //to make writing [0] optional
    public ListNode this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return List[0][name];
        }
    }
}
```

With such wrappers you can create a tree structure like this:

```
var node1 = new DictionaryNode();
var node2 = new ListNode();
var node3 = new DictionaryNode();
var node4 = new ListNode();
node4.List.AddRange(new[] { new DictionaryNode(), new DictionaryNode() });
node3.Dictionary.Add("bb", node4);
node2.List.Add(node3);
node1.Dictionary.Add("aa", node2);

var n = node1["aa"][0]["bb"][1];
var n2 = node1["aa"]["bb"][1];
```

Comment: I totaly forgot about that possibility and after a bit of trouble i adapt your solution to my needs, thanks a lot !!

Howewher you missed the result i have to add to ListNode as string when there is no child node left. I then could not add the final content of a node since a DictionnaryNode was expected. 

But don't worry i create a third non-generic class that inheritate from DictionnaryNode, works realy well !

Answer (score 0):

I used following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
  <line1>
    <value1>C1ligne1 1</value1>
    <value2>C1ligne1 2</value2>
  </line1>
  <line2>
    <value1>C1ligne2 1</value1>
    <value2>C1ligne2 2</value2>
  </line2>
  <line1>
    <value1>C2ligne1 1</value1>
    <value2>C2ligne1 2</value2>
  </line1>
  <line2>
    <value1>C2ligne2 1</value1>
    <value2>C2ligne2 2</value2>
  </line2>
</test>
```

Here is code to create two level dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> dict = doc.Element("test").Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y.Elements()
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Name.LocalName, b => (string)b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution work realy well and it's the one with the best performance. Howewer, if the Xml have more than two level of nodes (like an LDAP tree) it would be difficult. But i'll probably use your solution for future two level dictionnary, i like it !

Comment: The you need to use a recursive method.  Do it many times before.